# PyGTK: CellRendererPixbuf and transparency

Tags: python, colors, gtk, transparency, pygtk

I'm using PyGTK and I want to draw something inside a CellRenderer, so I'm using a CellRendererPixbuff, and it's working. The only problem is that if that drawing has transparency, the output will be bad and mixed up.

Screenshot: http://postimage.org/image/f839ijd0/

My code:

```
def pixbufSqFromColor(color, size, roundR=0):## a rounded square with specified color
    pmap = gdk.Pixmap(None, size, size, depth=24)
    cr = pmap.cairo_create()
    ###
    #cr.rectangle(0, 0, size, size)
    #fillColor(cr, (255, 255, 255, 0))
    ###
    cr.move_to(roundR, 0)
    cr.line_to(size-roundR, 0)
    cr.arc(size-roundR, roundR, roundR, 3*pi/2, 2*pi) ## up right corner
    cr.line_to(size, size-roundR)
    cr.arc(size-roundR, size-roundR, roundR, 0, pi/2) ## down right corner
    cr.line_to(roundR, size)
    cr.arc(roundR, size-roundR, roundR, pi/2, pi) ## down left corner
    cr.line_to(0, roundR)
    cr.arc(roundR, roundR, roundR, pi, 3*pi/2) ## up left corner
    ###
    cr.close_path()
    fillColor(cr, color)
    ####
    pbuf = gdk.Pixbuf(gdk.COLORSPACE_RGB, True, 8, size, size)
    colormap = gtk.gdk.colormap_get_system()
    #colormap = self.get_screen().get_system_colormap()
    #colormap = pmap.get_colormap()
    pbuf.get_from_drawable(pmap, colormap, 0, 0, 0, 0, size, size)
    return pbuf
    #return gdk.Pixbuf.get_from_drawable(pmap, gdk.COLORSPACE_RGB, 0, 0, 0, 0, size, size)
```

And this is where that function is used

```
        groupNode = self.treestore.append((
            -1,
            group.enable,
            pixbufSqFromColor(group.color, 50, 15),
            group.title,
            '',
        ))
```

And some used functions here:

```
def setColor(cr, color):
    ## arguments to set_source_rgb and set_source_rgba must be between 0 and 1
    if len(color)==3:
        cr.set_source_rgb(color[0] / 255.0,
                          color[1] / 255.0,
                          color[2] / 255.0)
    elif len(color)==4:
        cr.set_source_rgba(color[0] / 255.0,
                           color[1] / 255.0,
                           color[2] / 255.0,
                           color[3] / 255.0)
    else:
        raise ValueError('bad color %s'%str(color))


def fillColor(cr, color):
    setColor(cr, color)
    cr.fill()
```

Answer (score 1):

I've a similar problem and it seems to stem from `gdk.Pixmap` but I have no solution yet.

Edit :
I've solved my problem by using `gtk.gdk.pixbuf_new_from_xpm_data()` to generate the pixbuf, instead of `gdk.Pixmap` and Cairo operations. I know you can't use it because you have `size` and `roundR` parameters.

Maybe you can fill the `gdk.Pixmap` with a color that you'll replace with `gtk.gdk.Pixbuf.add_alpha()` when the pixbuf will be generated.

Comment: Thanks, The second solution is good, but (apearantly) not perfect. Becouse of vector drawing, see this screenshot: http://postimage.org/image/1dplqqls4/61343501/